# Adding subevents to Simile Timeline using a SharePoint 2010 calendar

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, calendar

I'm using Simile Timeline with a SharePoint 2010 calendar. How would I go about changing it to where I could add subevents that would be associated with events, so that each event would have its related subevents right under it in the chart? I haven't been able to find anything about this after much search.